# 12.04.2 LTS 32-bit Server does not start graphic interface in VMWare 5.0?

Tags: 12.04, vmware, lts

On a Windows 7 system, I installed VMWare 5.0 and tried to install the 32-bit Server LTS flavour of Ubuntu. After the install completed, it only starts in console instead of the usual GUI.

How do I get the GUI to appear? The install did not ask for the root password?

Answer (score 1):

A server normally doesn't include a GUI desktop. A likely short answer is to run this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

but see [community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) for more details and options. Don't miss "Arguments against a GUI (on a server)."

To your last point, no root pw, the Ubuntu installer does not set up a root user. Still, your normal user will have sudo privileges, and you can add a root user if you wish.